# Caffe: can't open imagenet_mean_test.binaryproto

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

Upon running `./train_caffenet.sh`; creating the layer data, setting up the data, loading the training `mean.binaryproto` file and opening the training lmdb file all works.

However when it comes to loading the test `mean.binaryproto` file for the test data I get the following error:

> Loading mean file from: /home/pwhc/caffe/Learn/imagenet_mean_test.binaryproto
>   F0716 13:12:13.917732  3385 db.hpp:109] Check failed: mdb_status == 0 (2 vs. 0) No such file or directory
>   *** Check failure stack trace: ***
>       @     0x7f8337946daa  (unknown)
>       @     0x7f8337946ce4  (unknown)
>       @     0x7f83379466e6  (unknown)
>       @     0x7f8337949687  (unknown)
>       @     0x7f8337cbf5be  caffe::db::LMDB::Open()
>       @     0x7f8337d16b82  caffe::DataLayer<>::DataLayerSetUp()
>       @     0x7f8337d806f9  caffe::BasePrefetchingDataLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
>       @     0x7f8337ca3db3  caffe::Net<>::Init()
>       @     0x7f8337ca5b22  caffe::Net<>::Net()
>       @     0x7f8337cb0a24  caffe::Solver<>::InitTestNets()
>       @     0x7f8337cb111b  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
>       @     0x7f8337cb12e6  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
>       @           0x40c4c0  caffe::GetSolver<>()
>       @           0x406503  train()
>       @           0x404ab1  main
>       @     0x7f8336e58ec5  (unknown)
>       @           0x40505d  (unknown)
>       @              (nil)  (unknown)
>   Aborted (core dumped)

I modified the `train_val.prototxt` to point the to appropriate `mean.binaryproto` files (using absolute paths) and have checked and double checked to make sure everything matches.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can \`No such file or directory\` only mean that there is \`No such file or directory\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588346/can-no-such-file-or-directory-only-mean-that-there-is-no-such-file-or-directo)

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2780#issuecomment-123385714

Can you post your data layers? It seems like you've switched up `data_param.source` and `transform_param.mean_file`.

Answer (score 0):

When you creating new LMDB database from image net, please delete the previous LMDB. This error will come to happen when writing the new image net data for existing LMDB database.