# Cannot find mean file while training on Imagenet

Tags: caffe, imagenet

I am trying to train and validate a network on Imagenet. The validation process works without any problems (with the pretrained weights). However, when I try to perform the training, there appears an error that the `imagenet_mean.binaryproto` file is not found; the very same file that has worked for the valiudation process. What is wrong?

```
...
I0222 15:29:15.108032 15823 net.cpp:399] data -> label
I0222 15:29:15.108057 15823 data_transformer.cpp:25] Loading mean file from: /home/myuser/learning/caffe/data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto
F0222 15:29:15.108577 15830 db_lmdb.hpp:14] Check failed: mdb_status == 0 (2 vs. 0) No such file or directory
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fc82857edaa  (unknown)
    @     0x7fc82857ece4  (unknown)
    @     0x7fc82857e6e6  (unknown)
    @     0x7fc828581687  (unknown)
    @     0x7fc828ba115e  caffe::db::LMDB::Open()
    @     0x7fc828b75644  caffe::DataReader::Body::InternalThreadEntry()
    @     0x7fc828cc1470  caffe::InternalThread::entry()
    @     0x7fc81f4a8a4a  (unknown)
    @     0x7fc826a98184  start_thread
    @     0x7fc8271b437d  (unknown)
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is the prototxt I am using:

```
name: "CaffeNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: true
    crop_size: 227
    mean_file: "/home/myuser/learning/caffe/data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto"
    #mean_file: "data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto"
  }
# mean pixel / channel-wise mean instead of mean image
#  transform_param {
#    crop_size: 227
#    mean_value: 104
#    mean_value: 117
#    mean_value: 123
#    mirror: true
#  }
  data_param {
    source: "examples/imagenet/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 256
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: false
    crop_size: 227
    mean_file: "/home/myuser/learning/caffe/data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto"
    #mean_file: "data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto"
  }
# mean pixel / channel-wise mean instead of mean image
#  transform_param {
#    crop_size: 227
#    mean_value: 104
#    mean_value: 117
#    mean_value: 123
#    mirror: false
#  }
  data_param {
    source: "/sdc/repository/myuser/Imagenet2012/Imagenet2012trainLMDB"
    #source: "examples/imagenet/ilsvrc12_val_lmdb"
    batch_size: 50
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
…
```

Comment: Your error message means that caffe can't open `examples/imagenet/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb` not `imagenet_mean.binaryproto`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can \`No such file or directory\` only mean that there is \`No such file or directory\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588346/can-no-such-file-or-directory-only-mean-that-there-is-no-such-file-or-directo)